# Visual Studio Express Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have developed an application in visual studio express edition 2010. Now i want to deploy it. But express edition does not support "Setup and deployment". So How to do setup?

Comment: Using WPF, Winforms...?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of application is this? If it is simple exe and some files, you could potentially just zip them and ask the user to unzip them and start using it.

If you want zing bang - a wizard to walk the user through setup, program icons, icons in startup menu etc, then you need a program to 'write' the msi for you. See e.g. this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/).

> WiX--the Windows Installer XML toolset--lets developers create installers for Windows Installer, the Windows installation engine.